# How can I record block solve times on OSX?

Tags: blockchain, development, mac

I need to be able to record the times blocks are solved as they are solved. Bitcoin-abe would be nice (overkill, actually) but I can't get it working on my mac.

Anyone know of a mac compatible method of recording block timestamps?

Comment: Your best bet might be to [file a bug](https://github.com/jtobey/bitcoin-abe/issues) with the ABE team.

Comment: I don't think it's a bug, more likely my inability to get OSX running python properly. But I don't need everything that Abe provides, just the block times.